# A separation lemma in a real vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, topological-vector-spaces

A *lattice* $N$ is a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module of finite rank. Let $V$ be the real vector space $N\otimes_\mathbb{Z} \mathbb{R}.$ A *cone* is a set $\sigma = \{ r_1 v_1 + \ldots + r_k v_k \in V : r_i\geq 0 \}$ where the $v_i\in V.$ The dual space of $V$ is $V'$ and the *dual cone* of $\sigma$ is $$\sigma^{\vee}:=\{ f\in V' : f(x)\geq 0 \ \text{for all} \ x\in \sigma \}.$$

I want to prove that if $x_o\notin \sigma$ then there is some $f\in \sigma^{\vee}$ such that $f(x_0) < 0.$ I think we can prove this by first noticing that $V$ is a finite dimensional real vector space. As such, we can endow some locally convex Hausdorff topology on it (for example the one induced by an inner product defined by $ \langle e_i, e_j \rangle = \delta_{ij}$ for some basis $\{ e_i \})$. Then one can construct the desired $f$ as t.b. has done at the end of his answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/68518/41464).

The result I want to prove is purely algebraic, there are no topologies *a priori* on any of the objects. As such the above proof feels unsatisfactory. Can someone find a proof that does not put a topology on $V$ first?

Comment: I think that you can use the fact that $(V')'$ is canonically isomorphic to $V$ and you should be able to show that through this embedding that $\sigma$ gets mapped to the dual cone of $\sigma^V$. This should do it.