# Conditions for $A = (A^*)^*$

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization

We have set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n $ and define $A^*$ as 
$$ A^* := \{s \in \mathbb{R}^n : x^Ts \geq 0, \forall x \in A \}$$

Suppose $A^*$ is nonempty. What are the conditions needed for $A = (A^*)^*$?

(Question actually asks to prove (or disprove) that $A$ is a closed convex cone.)

Comment: Sketch: The dual of a set is a cone, and the dual of a cone is a closed convex cone. So A** is a closed convex cone, and if A** = A then A is a closed convex cone. Conversely, if A is a closed convex cone, then since A** is the closure of A when A is a cone, and A is closed, we have A** = A.

Comment: @RagibZaman you mentioned that "A** is the closure of A when A is a cone". Why is this so?

Comment: That fact should be developed in the text that you are learning from, but you can also find it here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/28727

Comment: Got it. Thanks!